# How to compare two columns values after partitioning the table in SQL Redshift

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I have 4 columns in a table (Person_ID, Account_Name, Account_ID, Account_IDs). For each person id, I want to find all of those Account_ID that don't exist in Account_IDs column for that person_ID. Below is a sample table:

```
    Person_id Account_Name Account_ID Account_IDs
--------------------------------------------------
123 Name3   ,000000ihi4MAQ, ,000000TF5MAHZ,000000TF5MAQQ,000000grVA6AM,000000ihi4MAQ,000016ILMhAO,
123 Name2   ,000016ILMhAO,  ,000000TF5MAHZ,000000TF5MAQQ,000000grVA6AM,000000ihi4MAQ,000016ILMhAO,
123 Name1   ,000000grVA6AM, ,000000TF5MAHZ,000000TF5MAQQ,000000grVA6AM,000000ihi4MAQ,000016ILMhAO,
123 Name4   ,000000TF5MAQQ, ,000000TF5MAHZ,000000TF5MAQQ,000000grVA6AM,000000ihi4MAQ,000016ILMhAO,
123 Name5   ,000000TF5MAHZ, ,000000TF5MAHZ,000000TF5MAQQ,000000grVA6AM,000000ihi4MAQ,000016ILMhAO,
124 Name2   ,000016ILMhAO,  ,000000frVA6AM,000016ILMhAO,
124 Name7   ,000024ILMhAO,  ,000000frVA6AM,000016ILMhAO,
124 Name8   ,000000frVA7XZ, ,000000frVA6AM,000016ILMhAO,
124 Name5   ,000000TF5MAHZ, ,000000frVA6AM,000016ILMhAO,
124 Name6   ,000000frVA6AM, ,000000frVA6AM,000016ILMhAO,
125 Name11  ,000000frXC6A,  ,000000frVA6BC,000024ILMhJZ,000000frXC6A,000024YTMhA,
125 Name9   ,000000frVA6BC, ,000000frVA6BC,000024ILMhJZ,000000frXC6A,000024YTMhA,
125 Name10  ,000024ILMhJZ,  ,000000frVA6BC,000024ILMhJZ,000000frXC6A,000024YTMhA,
125 Name12  ,000024YTMhA,   ,000000frVA6BC,000024ILMhJZ,000000frXC6A,000024YTMhA,
125 Name13  ,000024IXThJY,  ,000000frVA6BC,000024ILMhJZ,000000frXC6A,000024YTMhA,
```

So from this sample, the answer should be:

```
Person_ID   Account_ID      Account_Name
-----------------------------------------

   124      000000TF5MAHZ     Name5
   124      000024ILMhAO      Name7
   124      000000frVA7XZ     Name8
   125      000024IXThJY      Name13
```

I couldn't understand how to compare values in two columns after partitioning the table.

Thank you for your help in advance.

Comment: What are the data types of your columns?  Are you really storing a list as a string?  If so, fix your data model!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that `Account_IDs` is a string containing comma-separated values, use:

```sql
WHERE Account_IDs NOT LIKE '%' || Account_ID || '%'
```